# Phrase to describe "wow" or "amazing" (sounds like 'pang')

Tags: word-choice

There was a word a friend mentioned which meant something to the effect of "wow" or "amazing" or "impressive" and the english pronunciation was similar to "pang" but I cannot be 100% certain.

Is there a Chinese/Sichuanese phrase that sounds like "pang" used to describe excitement?

(or perhaps if my memory is really hazy, it sounded like "bang" or "pong" or something like that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Know nothing at all of Sichuanese, but maybe you mean 棒 bang in it's sense of 'great, wonderful'

linedict: 我认为这部电影非常棒！

iciba:wow might be 哇：我想：“哇，多好的主意呀。”

Comment: Yes, that is it !    棒
Thank-you.

Comment: 不用谢应该的！I get lots of help here too! iciba has lots of sentences, just their English is, to say the very least, questionable at times.